# Failed to start logic app run for Event Grid trigger

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-eventgrid

I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-to-event-grid-integration-example?toc=%2Fazure%2Fevent-grid%2Ftoc.json) to send a message from service bus topic to email using Event Grid.

When I run the Logic App, I get the following error:

> Failed to start a run of logic app test-servicebusq. The template language expression evaluation failed: 'The execution of template trigger 'When_a_resource_event_occurs' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'splitOn' expression '@triggerBody()' is of type 'Null'. The result must be a valid array.'

When I send a message to the service bus, the logic app does not get triggered at all.

I have turned of the 'splitOn' and when I run the logic app manually, the trigger gets fired and the logic app is executed, but when I send a message to the service bus topic, the trigger does not get triggered automatically (unless I manually Run the logic app).

I want the logic app to be automatically triggered when a new message arrives in the service bus.

Is there something I am doing wrong? I followed the tutorial step by step and I am still unable to figure out what is the problem. Do I need to create an event grid resource somewhere? (it is not mentioned in the tutorial)

Edit: I am using the following code to send the message

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage

connstr = <connection string>
topic_name = "fileincomplete"


with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(connstr) as client:
    with client.get_topic_sender(topic_name) as sender:
        sender.send_messages(ServiceBusMessage("Data12"))
```

Comment: Can you make sure that the suffix filter and the subscription name are the same?

Comment: Yes the suffix and subscription name is the name

Comment: Can you please add what code you are using while sending messages?

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda-MT I have added  the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing in my local environment, I could able to make this work after mentioning the Event Type Item. Below is my logic app flow.

[image]

I am using the below code to send the messages

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage

CONNECTION_STR = "<YOUR_NAMESPACE_CONNECTION_STRING>"
TOPIC_NAME = "<YOUR_TOPIC_NAME>" 

servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR, logging_enable=True)

with servicebus_client:
    sender = servicebus_client.get_topic_sender(topic_name=TOPIC_NAME)
    with sender:
        message = ServiceBusMessage("Data12")
        sender.send_messages(message)
        print("Sent a single message")
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! let me try and see if it works.

Comment: The trigger doesn't get fired when I send the message and the logic app does not run. I am not sure how to further debug it to find the problem. Could there be any permissions/access issue?

Comment: Do I need to create some Event Grid subscription resource something?

Comment: @Rebe Can you try making all the settings to default and try once again

Comment: I did that too. Does not work. Can you please tell me which plan are your using for service bus? Are you using premium plan? and which region?

Comment: It is premium and North central US

Comment: I think that is the problem, I have a standard one

Comment: @Rebe Try upgrading it to premium as mentioned in the documentation

Comment: Please refrain from having conversations in comments - that's not what comments are for.  And this comment section is unnecessarily long.